# Is there a way to use the same skills for the same units being controlled by Chen without pressing tab?

Tags: dota-2

For example, you have 3 centaurs in the same group, and you press the stun hotkey, the first centaur will perform the stun skill and you have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the next centaur before pressing the stun hotkey. This is slow and the millisecond you spend pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> can mean the difference between landing consecutive stuns and the opponent escaping, especially due to the new feature in Dota 2 called status resistance.

This is also annoying if you are controlling 3 units of satyrs in the same group and the shockwave will not be released in succession fast enough because of this <kbd>Tab</kbd> mechanic that you need to execute.

In *Warcraft 3* (original *Dota*), this is not a problem as you can just press the same hot key over and over again, and the units in the same group will perform the spell without pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and they do it in order of the 1st to last unit, very convenient.

Anyone who knows how to put the script from *Warcraft 3* please help me put it in *Dota 2*.